# How to compute a Boltzmann-weighted average (including normalization) for an observable in a system with a finite number of states?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

Suppose I have an observable $x$, a scalar quantity, in the canonical ensemble. One way to compute the average value of $x$ is to calculate the arithmetic mean
$$\begin{aligned} \langle x \rangle_{\text{arithmetic}} &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}\end{aligned}$$
for $N$ states of the system. $x_i$ is the value of $x$ when the system is in the $i$th state. The
$\frac{1}{N}$ factor normalizes the average.

But suppose I want to calculate a Boltzmann-weighted average. How do I do this? I think it may be something like the following for $N$ states:
$$\begin{aligned} \langle x \rangle_{\text{Boltzmann}} &= A\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i}\exp(-E_{i}/k_{B}T)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \exp(-E_{i}/k_{B}T)}\end{aligned}$$
for $N$ states of the system. $x_i$ is the value of $x$ when the system is in the $i$th state, $E_{i}$ is the energy of the $i$th state, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the absolute temperature, and $A$ is a normalization constant.

Note that I'm considering a finite number $N$ of states. In fact, in my simulations, $N = 3$ only.

Is the above expression for $\langle x \rangle_{\text{Boltzmann}}$ correct? If so, what is the proper normalization condition, in order to determine $A$?

Comment: You don't need the $A$. It is already normalized with $p_i = \exp(-\beta E_i)/\sum_j\exp(-\beta E_j)$ since $\sum_i p_i = 1$

Comment: This is in any statistical mechanics book, the derivation is simple, it won't take much time.

Comment: I don't get your "arithmetic mean", this is only true in the microcanonical ensemble: states with equal energy are equiprobable. It is not true that any two states occur with the same probability.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it may be something like the following for $N$ states:
> $$\begin{aligned} \langle x \rangle_{\text{Boltzmann}} &= A\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i}\exp(-E_{i}/k_{B}T)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \exp(-E_{i}/k_{B}T)}\end{aligned}$$
> for $N$ states of the system.

> Is the above expression for $\langle x \rangle_{\text{Boltzmann}}$ correct?

It is correct if you set $A=1$.

> If so, what is the proper normalization condition, in order to determine $A$?

The normalization constant has already been established by the
$$
Z = \sum_j e^{-\beta E_j}
$$
in the denominator. $Z$ is known as the partition function, which, despite being "only" a normalization constant, it is a very useful function in statistical mechanics.

You are already normalized since
$$
p_i = e^{-\beta E_i}/Z
$$
and so
$$
\sum_i p_i = \frac{Z}{Z} = 1\;.
$$

With your $A=1$, the average is a proper average since the probabilities $p_i$ sum up to one as they should.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that $Z$ isn't just letter, it is _the_ partition function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)

Comment: Yes, it is the partition function.

Answer (score 0):

The (standard) average $\bar x = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ can be written as
$\bar x =  \sum_{i=1}^N p_i x_i$, where $p_i = \frac{1}{N}$ is the probability for the $x_i$ to occur. E.g. if we have a fair cube with $N$ sides, the probability for each side to appear is $1/N$. A second example is an urn with $N$ different balls.

Next, we say that the probability of the $i^{th}$ state to appear is
$p_i = \frac{\exp(-\beta E_i)}{Z}$, where $Z = \sum_i \exp(-\beta E_i)$ is the normalisation factor. As the upper formula is still valid, we just plug this in and obtain
$$
\bar x = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i x_i
= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\exp(-\beta E_i)}{Z} \;x_i
= \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{i=1}^N \exp(-\beta E_i)\; x_i
$$